# Using Win32_Process.GetOwner in C++

Tags: c++, wmi

I'm trying to use the WMI class Win32_Process to get a list of running processes and the users who are the owners of each process. The enumeration of processes using Win32_Process in C++ wasn't that difficult using the enumeration example from MSDN ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=vs.85).aspx)) and simply changing Win32_OperatingSystem to Win32_Process. I have found that by using the GetOwner method of Win32_Process I can get the user and domain of the owner of a process. There is a great example of this in VB ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390460(v=vs.85).aspx)) which shows that I can use the enumerator object to call the specific instance of GetOwner for the process information at any given point in the enumeration.

I have attempted to use the code example ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390421(v=vs.85).aspx)) for "Calling a Provider Method" to figure out how to make the method call to GetOwner but I cannot figure out how to get it to work. I am continually hitting road blocks. typically I get the invalid method parameters. Take the following code chunk

```
        BSTR MethodName = SysAllocString(L"GetOwner");
        BSTR ClassName = SysAllocString(L"Win32_Process");

        IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
        hres = pSvc->GetObject(ClassName, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);
        printf("[1] hres = %08x\n", hres);

        IWbemClassObject* pInParamsDefinition = NULL;
        IWbemClassObject* pOutParams = NULL;
        hres = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0, &pInParamsDefinition, &pOutParams);
        printf("[2] hres = %08x (%08x, %08x)\n", hres, pInParamsDefinition, pOutParams);

        // Execute Method
        hres = pSvc->ExecMethod(L"Win32_Process", MethodName, 0, NULL, NULL, &pOutParams, NULL);

        VARIANT varReturnValue;
        hres = pOutParams->Get(_bstr_t(L"ReturnValue"), 0,
            &varReturnValue, NULL, 0);
        wprintf(L"The command is: %s\n", V_BSTR(&varReturnValue));
```

GetOwner has not input parameters and when I call GetMethod the pInParamsDefinition always returns NULL while pOutParams returns a ptr. Since there isn't a pointer returned to pInParamsDefinition, I can't supply inputs and as such I don't know how to get around the invalid method parameters issue. Clearly WMI programming isn't my strongest skill :)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

After messing around off and on for a while, i finally figured out the answer to my own question. The problem is that you need to specify what object you want to execute the method against. To do this, you call GetObject("__PATH", ...) to get the path to the object currently being enumerated and you pass the result of the GetObject (a BSTR) to ExecMethod as the first argument. This tells the method, in my case GetOwner, what you are trying to execute against. Here's a sample program I wrote that dumps the current list of processes and their owner.

```js
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 HRESULT hres;

 // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
 // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

 hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
 if (FAILED(hres))
 {
  cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x"
   << hex << hres << endl;
  return 1;                  // Program has failed.
 }

 // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
 // Set general COM security levels --------------------------

 hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
  NULL,
  -1,                          // COM authentication
  NULL,                        // Authentication services
  NULL,                        // Reserved
  RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
  RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
  NULL,                        // Authentication info
  EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
  NULL                         // Reserved
  );


 if (FAILED(hres))
 {
  cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x"
   << hex << hres << endl;
  CoUninitialize();
  return 1;                    // Program has failed.
 }

 // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
 // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

 IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

 hres = CoCreateInstance(
  CLSID_WbemLocator,
  0,
  CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
  IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *)&pLoc);

 if (FAILED(hres))
 {
  cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
   << " Err code = 0x"
   << hex << hres << endl;
  CoUninitialize();
  return 1;                 // Program has failed.
 }

 // Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
 // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

 IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

 // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
 // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
 // to make IWbemServices calls.
 hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
  _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
  NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
  NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
  0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
  NULL,                    // Security flags.
  0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
  0,                       // Context object 
  &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
  );

 if (FAILED(hres))
 {
  cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x"
   << hex << hres << endl;
  pLoc->Release();
  CoUninitialize();
  return 1;                // Program has failed.
 }

 cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;


 // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
 // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------

 hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
  pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
  RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
  RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
  NULL,                        // Server principal name 
  RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
  RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
  NULL,                        // client identity
  EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
  );

 if (FAILED(hres))
 {
  cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x"
   << hex << hres << endl;
  pSvc->Release();
  pLoc->Release();
  CoUninitialize();
  return 1;               // Program has failed.
 }

 BSTR MethodName = SysAllocString(L"GetOwner");
 BSTR ClassName = SysAllocString(L"Win32_Process");

 // get the object containing our desired method
 IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
 hres = pSvc->GetObject(ClassName, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);
 if (FAILED(hres))
 {
  printf("GetObject hres = %08x\n", hres);
  pSvc->Release();
  pLoc->Release();
  CoUninitialize();
  return 1;
 }
 
 // get the desired method
 // in our case, we only need pmethodGetOwner since GetOwner really only has output
 IWbemClassObject* pmethodGetOwner = NULL;
 hres = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0, NULL, &pmethodGetOwner);
 if (FAILED(hres))
 {
  printf("GetMethod hres = %08x\n", hres);
  pSvc->Release();
  pLoc->Release();
  CoUninitialize();
  return 1;
 }

 // spawn the instance of the method
 IWbemClassObject* pInInst = NULL;
 hres = pmethodGetOwner->SpawnInstance(0, &pInInst);
 if (FAILED(hres))
 {
  printf("SpawnInstance hres = %08x\n", hres);
  pSvc->Release();
  pLoc->Release();
  CoUninitialize();
  return 1;
 }

 // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
 // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

 // For example, get the name of the operating system
 IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
 hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
  bstr_t("WQL"),
  bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process"),
  WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
  NULL,
  &pEnumerator);

 if (FAILED(hres))
 {
  cout << "Query for operating system name failed."
   << " Error code = 0x"
   << hex << hres << endl;
  pSvc->Release();
  pLoc->Release();
  CoUninitialize();
  return 1;               // Program has failed.
 }

 // Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
 // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

 IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
 ULONG uReturn = 0;

 while (pEnumerator)
 {
  HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

  if (0 == uReturn)
  {
   break;
  }

  VARIANT vtProp;
  VARIANT vtProcName;
  VARIANT vtDomain;
  VARIANT vtUsername;

  // Get the value of the Name property
  hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProcName, 0, 0);
  if (FAILED(hres))
  {
   printf("Failed to get the process's name\n");
   pclsObj->Release();
   continue;
  }

  // Get the PATH to the object in question
  // the result in vtProp is similar to '\\name_of_computer\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process.Handle="pid_of_process"'
  hr = pclsObj->Get(L"__PATH", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
  if (FAILED(hres))
  {
   printf("Failed to get the path to the object\n");
   pclsObj->Release();
   continue;
  }

  // Execute Method against the object defined by the __PATH variable
  hres = pSvc->ExecMethod(vtProp.bstrVal, MethodName, 0, NULL, NULL, &pmethodGetOwner, NULL);
  if (FAILED(hres))
  {
   wprintf(L"Failed to execute the method against %s\n", vtProp.bstrVal);
   pclsObj->Release();
   continue;
  }

  // extract the results
  hres = pmethodGetOwner->Get(L"User", 0, &vtUsername, NULL, 0);
  if (FAILED(hres))
  {
   printf("Failed to get the owner's name\n");
   pclsObj->Release();
   continue;
  }

  pmethodGetOwner->Get(L"Domain", 0, &vtDomain, NULL, 0);
  if (FAILED(hres))
  {
   printf("Failed to get the owner's domain\n");
   pclsObj->Release();
   continue;
  }

  // print the output to screen
  wprintf(L"Process: %s. Domain\\User: %s\\%s\n", V_BSTR(&vtProcName), V_BSTR(&vtDomain), V_BSTR(&vtUsername));

  // release/cleanup resources we used this go around
  VariantClear(&vtProcName);
  VariantClear(&vtProp);
  VariantClear(&vtDomain);
  VariantClear(&vtUsername);
  pclsObj->Release();

 }

 // Cleanup
 // ========

 pSvc->Release();
 pLoc->Release();
 pEnumerator->Release();
 CoUninitialize();

 return 0;   // Program successfully completed.

}
```

I was able to figure all of this out thanks to a random posting on google groups from 2002 (["Here is a WBem WMI C++ example"](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!msg/microsoft.public.wbem/XI_eQJTBzEk/AstVXudS4iMJ)).

I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Thanks @tjac, this helped me get around an issue I was having with calling a class method. I also found this which was super useful: [https://github.com/Microsoft/ctsTraffic](https://github.com/Microsoft/ctsTraffic). It has a great WMI utility which greatly reduces the boilerplate you have to type when working with WMI.